# kthread using 100% on cpu core checking kthread_should_stop()

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, queue, linux-device-driver

I have a queue of items that is filled by an interrupt driven process and being emptied by a kthread.

The problem is that the kthread that is emptying the queue is taking up 100% cpu of one of my cores. It appears that when the queue is empty, the while() loop constantly checks kthread_should_stop() repeatedly and only releases the core when I stop the thread.

```
#DEFINE MY_BUF_SIZE 100

struct item_struct {
    unsigned char buff[MY_BUF_SIZE];
    struct list_head list;
};  

struct  item_struct itemList;
struct task_struct *forward_items_thread;

void forward_items(void * args) {
    while (!kthread_should_stop()){
        struct item_struct *item, *tmpItem;

        list_for_each_entry_safe(item, tmpItem, &itemList.list, list)
        {
            my_send_items(item);
            list_del(&item->list);
            kfree(item);
        }
    }
}

void setup_item_forwarding(void){
    int err;

    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&itemList.list); 
    forward_items_thread = kthread_create(forward_items);
    if (IS_ERR(forward_items_thread)) {
        printk("kthread create failed");
        err = PTR_ERR(forward_items_thread);
        goto err_return;
    }

    err = wake_up_process(forward_items_thread);
    if (err == 1) {
        printk("forward_items_thread has woken.\n");
    }
    else {
        printk("forward_items_thread failed to wake.\n");
    }

err_return:
//do cleanup
}
```

I don't want to use sleeps/delays because the process that this is being used in is timing sensitive to ~1ms.

How do I make the kthread process the queued items without taking up so much time on the CPU?

Comment: Just make kthread to wait while the list is empty. using one of `wait_*` macros. There is some specific about `kthread_should_stop()`: 1. You need to check this condition together with list emptiness. 2. The wait should be *interruptible*, so stopping the thread will interrupt the wait.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `schedule()` after making the thread interruptible.

```
void forward_items(void * args) {
    while (!kthread_should_stop()){
        struct item_struct *item, *tmpItem;

        // set interruptible
        set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);

        // do I have anything to do ?
        if(my_func_no_task_to_do())
        {
             schedule();
        }

        list_for_each_entry_safe(item, tmpItem, &itemList.list, list)
        {
            my_send_items(item);
            list_del(&item->list);
            kfree(item);
        }
     }
}
```